# Query not executing in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
hive> create table daily_revenue as
select order_date, sum(order_item_subtotal) daily_revenue
from orders join order_items on
order_id = order_item_order_id
group by order_date;
```

After running the above query, I could not get the output as expected.

> output> Query ID = cloudera_20180323115454_7aff9398-59bd-4492-82e6-fa065251134e
>       Total jobs = 2
>       FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
>
> ErrorInformation> 
>   create table daily_revenue as
>   select order_date, sum(order_item_subtotal) daily_revenue
>   from orders join order_items on
>   order_id = order_item_order_id
>   where order_date like '2013-07%'
>   group by order_date
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,642 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(570)) - Semantic Analysis Completed
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,642 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:getSchema(303)) - Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:order_date, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:daily_revenue, type:double, comment:null)], properties:null)
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,643 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(690)) - Completed compiling command(queryId=cloudera_20180325184747_8e5480aa-b46d-41f4-8bea-6f2f4ffd737d); Time taken: 0.304 seconds
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,643 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:checkConcurrency(223)) - Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,643 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1656)) - Executing command(queryId=cloudera_20180325184747_8e5480aa-b46d-41f4-8bea-6f2f4ffd737d): create table daily_revenue as
>   select order_date, sum(order_item_subtotal) daily_revenue
>   from orders join order_items on
>   order_id = order_item_order_id
>   where order_date like '2013-07%'
>   group by order_date
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,643 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1080)) - Query ID = cloudera_20180325184747_8e5480aa-b46d-41f4-8bea-6f2f4ffd737d
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,643 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(1080)) - Total jobs = 1
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,658 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:launchTask(2039)) - Starting task [Stage-6:MAPREDLOCAL] in serial mode
>   2018-03-25 18:47:45,661 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(172)) - Generating plan file file:/tmp/cloudera/637b88e2-3c64-454d-b15a-eb95f3a501dd/hive_2018-03-25_18-47-45_338_6357453693718710628-1/-local-10006/plan.xml
>   2018-03-25 18:47:46,296 INFO  [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(319)) - Executing: /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec-1.1.0-cdh5.12.0.jar org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver -localtask -plan file:/tmp/cloudera/637b88e2-3c64-454d-b15a-eb95f3a501dd/hive_2018-03-25_18-47-45_338_6357453693718710628-1/-local-10006/plan.xml   -jobconffile file:/tmp/cloudera/637b88e2-3c64-454d-b15a-eb95f3a501dd/hive_2018-03-25_18-47-45_338_6357453693718710628-1/-local-10007/jobconf.xml
>   2018-03-25 18:47:46,309 ERROR [main]: mr.MapredLocalTask (MapredLocalTask.java:executeInChildVM(351)) - Exception: 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.executeInChildVM(MapredLocalTask.java:326)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.execute(MapredLocalTask.java:153)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:214)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:99)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2041)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1748)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1501)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1275)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:172)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:383)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:775)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:693)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>   2018-03-25 18:47:46,310 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(1103)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
>   2018-03-25 18:47:46,312 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1947)) - Completed executing command(queryId=cloudera_20180325184747_8e5480aa-b46d-41f4-8bea-6f2f4ffd737d); Time taken: 0.669 seconds

Comment: Please post the complete `Error trace`

Comment: the above error is thats all what i get

Comment: hive> SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;